# How to crop image to a frame

Tags: iphone, image-processing, uiimageview

I have UIImageView with frame size is 200 * 200. I would like to take a picture from camera or library which will fit to that frame.

Do you have any example to do it, like Instagram, Pose app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This method allows you to set a rect that you want to crop on the image, and returns the cropped image.  Enjoy your cropping :)

```
- (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)image inRect:(CGRect)rect  {
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, rect);
    UIImage *resultImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return resultImage;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your replying soon. Do you know how to create overlap cameraview like Instagram or Pose app ?

Comment: You would just create an image that looks like that, with a clear rect of 200 x 200 in the image, then based on the location of the image, you can use the method I posted above to crop it